# How to use 'SASS' from html template on a rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm trying to install an html template in my rails app, so I moved all the assets on public folder and renamed all the html files in erb.

Everything works fine except that 'sass' is not working, any file from the SASS folder of the html template is not doing their work.

So how can I make use of the SASS files of the html template on my rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I make use of the SASS files of the html template on my
>   rails app?

1) Install the SASS Gem `gem 'sass'` in your Gemfile if you're using `bundle install`, or via the command line: `gem install sass`

2) Create a file named 'manifest.txt' in your SASS folder, for example `public/src/sass/manifest.txt`

3) In `manifest.txt` list each file in the order of inclusion you want merged into a single CSS file, like:

```
framework.sass
framework_overides.sass
homepage.sass
contact.sass
global.sass
```

4) Open your `Rakefile` and create this rake task:

```
require 'sass'
desc "Parse SASS manifest.txt and convert to single CSS file"
task :sass do
  # your template directory
  src_dir = File.join Rails.root, 'public/src'

  # SASS directory
  sass_dir = File.join src_dir, "sass"

  # name of the single output file
  app_css_file = File.join src_dir, "css/application.css"

  # parse SASS manifest
  sass_manifest = IO.readlines File.join(sass_dir, "manifest.txt")

  # clear previous app_css_file, without having to require 'fileutils'
  File.open(app_css_file, 'w') {|f| f.write ""}

  # write to app_css_file
  File.open(app_css_file, 'a+') do |f|
    sass_manifest.each do |x|

      # remove code comments
      next if x.strip =~ /^#/

      # parse extension
      case syntax = File.extname(x.strip).delete('.').downcase

      # convert and append scss
      when /scss/ then
        f.write Sass::Engine.new(IO.read(File.join(sass_dir, x.strip)), :syntax => :scss, :cache => false).render

      # convert and append sass
      when /sass/ then
        f.write Sass::Engine.new(IO.read(File.join(sass_dir, x.strip)), :cache => false).render
      end
    end
  end
end
```

5) Use this command: `rake sass`

Comment: Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid @import: expected end of line, was ";".
(sass):1

Comment: @Ghamtre you cannot have `;` semicolons in your `.sass` files.

Comment: @Ghamtre by any chance are you using `SCSS`?

Comment: Yep :| I'm using SCSS

Comment: @Ghamtre no worries. Give me five min an I'll have an updated answer that will work with `.scss` files

Comment: @Ghamtre if this answer works for you, consider accepting it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/249307

Comment: Yeah is working, but I just caught this error Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: libs/vars.     > libs is a folder inside of the SASS folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116265/discussion-between-soawesomeman-and-ghamtre).

Answer (score 1):

For a bootstrap template I also faced the same kind of problem. So I'm sharing my experience, it may help you.
What I did was I removed this gem (if you are using this)

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

and replaced with this two gems,

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
```

you also need to initialize them in `application.js` and `application.css` according to its official [doc](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap).

Take a look at this [blog](http://rails-magic.blogspot.com/2016/05/how-to-integrate-custom-bootstrap-theme.html). Its a step-by-step about how to integrate custom bootstrap template in rails. It might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but now I have this error:  ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):

Comment: Its hard to tell just from one line, You should use some debugging tool like `byebug` or `pry` before the error line to find out whats wrong.